# Cannot realtime read from redis

Tags: php, laravel, controller, redis, real-time

I have a server long time running application which store process like this:

routes.php

```
Route::post('cloud/slice/{modelfileid}', 'CloudController@slice');
Route::get('cloud/slice/sliceProgress', 'CloudController@sliceProgress');
```

part of slice() function:

```
while($s = fgets($pipes[2]))
{
    if(strpos($s, "Progress:") !== FALSE)
    {
        Log::info(100 * substr($s, -10, 4) . '%');
        $this->redis->SET('sliceProgress' . $uid, 100 * substr($s, -10, 4) . '%');

    }
}
```

and my client every 0.5 second request the progress in the redis with this:

```
public function sliceProgress()
{
    if (!isset($_SESSION["uid"]))
        return Redirect::to('cloud');
    $uid = $_SESSION["uid"];
    return Response::json(array('status' => 'success', 'data' => array('progress' => $this->redis->GET('sliceProgress' . $uid))));
}
```

and

```
$interval(function()
{
    $scope.refreshProgress();
}, 500);
```

But the client get progress request will hold until to the end with 100%, without the progress that less than 100%. That is to say I get the progress response when the  server slice application finished. I suppose laravel don't process the second request when it processing the slice.

---

> Edited:
>   I use below code to get the redis in the slice() after the redis->SET works well, this output the sliceProgress realtime.
>
> `Log::info($this->redis->GET('sliceProgress' . $uid));`

Comment: Totally don't understand your question. Try again?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial check it now.

Comment: @KrisRoofe what is your question?

Comment: @Bara'ayyash the question title, and the last but

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run this code in a background process like async queues or crons

```
while($s = fgets($pipes[2]))
{
if(strpos($s, "Progress:") !== FALSE)
{
    Log::info(100 * substr($s, -10, 4) . '%');
    $this->redis->SET('sliceProgress' . $uid, 100 * substr($s, -10, 4) . '%');

}
}
```

Comment: some explain may be more helphul. Thansk all the same.

Comment: try to make a command using laravel commands, or async queues using this package https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-async-queue

Comment: I think you're right, you suggestion is a good implementation.  But I also want to know, why the second request will hold until the first finished.

Comment: if you tried to make `return "test"` in the first line of `sliceProgress()` , will it also wait for the progress to be finished ?

Comment: if it wait even if the function does nothing except return a string, then that means, the process will be occupied by the  `sliceProgress` request, and it can serve nothing until the previous request is resolved. so if you want to do something like `sliceProgress` you should do it in another process, this why i suggested using commands and async queues

Comment: I don't know why, requests form the same user to the methods of the same laravel controller are processed one by one, cannot pataller. Is requests from same user to diffrent laravel controller, or different requests from different user to same controller, can processed parallel.

Comment: by using laravel as long time running application, it will be the same id for process that runs the application

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem could be Session Lock. Consider you fired POST request following the Multiple GET calls. Now if session lock is there, none of the get request will be handled by PHP until the first one is done.

**How Session Lock works?**
Well php simply lock the session file to read, so all other apache processes have to wait. Laravel also use file based session management, so.

Now removing session lock is not a good idea, though you can do that. Try exposing this Get Service from different host or port.

I am not 100% sure how laravel handles session lock, so just cross check if this is the issue.

**Removing Session Lock:**
First Way: Use method once you done with session handling [session_write_close](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php).
Second : Pass read_and_close to be *true* while starting session with [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Not sure whether laravel allows to do that. There are other ways of doing realtime progress sync.

Comment: where can I have a dip dig for the session lock.